# optimized query of 2 tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 2 tables.

```
Restaurant
------------------
id, name, address

Inspection
---------------------------------------------
id, result, date_of_inspection, restaurant_id
```

Now each Restaurant have 1 or more inspections. So what i want to do is list out all the restaurants and show their latest inspection_result.

Is it possible to do this in 1 query and without having the result set contain 1 row for each inspection?

Ideally each returned row would contain something like this:

```
Result row
------------------------------------
restaurantid, name, address, result
```

Comment: Well, i have no idea how to get this done in one statement. What I've tried so far is this:    select restaurant.id as restId, restaurant.name as restName from restaurant, inspection where restaurant.id = inspection.restaurantid. If there have been 3 inspections, i will get 1 row for each inspection.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select r.id, r.name, r.address, 
     (select result from Inspection where restaurant_id = r.id order by date_of_inspection desc  LIMIT 1) as result
from Restaurant r
```

Comment: top 1 is TSQL, not SQLite, no?